# IFERROR VLOOKUP Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-formula

Frustration finally boiled over and had to post here.

I have a Google Sheet where I want a sheet (LOG) to have a formula that will search for a name on a different sheet (DAY 1), and if the name has a value in the cell adjacent to it, that the formula on DAILY return that adjacent cell value.

Right now, I am using an IFERROR to lead the equation. This will return a value of "0" for when a name does not occur (since different names will occur on different days).

Then I attempt a VLOOKUP, and I think I'm putting the criteria in correctly, but it doesn't give me the answer I want. That is in the document, I want cell B4 on page LOG to reflect that the name Smith, John is found on the page DAY 1, and that there is a value on cell C4.

Can anyone assist with this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tS6gqtEpp55OJpYa1jSMKmbm8qU5ZzRu0rqFWHegi0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,'Day 1'!A4:A13, 3,FALSE, 0))
```

1. You specify parameter 3 - colindex=3 while parameter 2 - range consists of one column
2. Incorrect placement of brackets

Correct formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,'Day 1'!A4:C13, 3,FALSE), 0)
```

Comment: Hello "basic" thanks for the quick reply. I did some quick tests and it seems to have resolved the problem, so thank you very much! If you have the time, I would appreciate some more insight as to how this formula works... I just reread the Google Sheets pop-up formula help and where I got confused is I wanted the range to explicitly search the first column, not realizing this would make it impossible to then find that other data point. Thank you for helping me realize this!

Comment: OK, then accept my answer so that the question does not remain open. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `VLOOKUP` isn't your best option, try using `SUMIFS` instead:

```
=SUMIFS('Day 1'!$C$4:$C$13,'Day 1'!$A$4:$A$13,A4)
```

This function fills your need.

I would also recommend having one tab for all your "raw" data for each day like this:

[image: Day 1 Tab]

And using this formula instead, you can drag right and down now:

```
=SUMIFS('Day 1'!$D$4:$D,'Day 1'!$A$4:$A,B$2,'Day 1'!$B$4:$B,$A4)
```

[image: Log Tab]

Hope you find this more useful :)
-this is my first post

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXgZfKvUt7lrp4E8tAqaYEmSmZwjEbDYcQD8j1jHReY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here is link to the doc:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXgZfKvUt7lrp4E8tAqaYEmSmZwjEbDYcQD8j1jHReY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, and thanks a lot for your contribution ;) I suggest you take a look at this link which may help you provide better formatted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Thanks again!!

Comment: @carlesgg97 Thanks for the formatting help! Will keep this in mind moving forward!!